# AJAX/PHP Form Data Not Submitting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a website for a friend. He has a basic "Contact Me" section. I'm wanting to use AJAX and PHP to submit the form.

Here is the form html.

```
div class="contactme" id="contactme">  
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="myemailform" id="myform" action="form-to-email.php">
          <fieldset>
            <h2>Let's Create Together</h2>
            <hr class="small">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="visitor_email" placeholder="E-Mail">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="message"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary mainButton">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
</div>
```

Here is jquery AJAX code snippet.

```
//AJAX FORM SUBMISSION
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submitbutton').on('submit', function(){
                //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
                e.preventDefault();
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'form-to-email.php',
                    data: {name: email},
                    success: function(){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

And here is my PHP file that e-mails the responses from the user.

```
    <?php
if (!isset ($_POST ['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submist the form. 
    echo "error, you need to submit the form!";
}

$name = $_POST ['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST ['visitor_email'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];

//Validation

if(empty ($name)||empty ($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit();
}

else {
    echo "Submit Successful!";
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit(); 
}


$email_from = 'info@joshkelley.video'; //<== Put your email address here
$email_subject = "New Form Submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "E-mail Address: $visitor_email\n".
    "Here is the message: $message\n".

$to = "brandontetrick@gmail.com"; // <==Put your email address here
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n"; 

//Send the email! 

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done


?>
```

Overall goal is for a basic submission of a "Contact Me" message, but the user doesn't leave the page. Every time I press the submit button, my validation fails and I get "Name and email are mandatory!" message.

The site is live if you want to take look. Still a work in progress. 
[joshkelley.video](http://joshkelley.video)

Comment: `data: {name: email},` -- the data you're posting only contains a "name", and not a "visitor_email" entry.

Comment: That helped, but its come back to my original problem. Posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428332/submit-form-redirect-back-to-index-html

Comment: @btetrick : updated my answer with redirection if that's what you needed (if I properly understood)

Answer (score 0):

you miss data, as you post only `name`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitbutton').on('submit', function(e){
       //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
         e.preventDefault();
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'form-to-email.php',
               data: {name: name, email: email}, /* there was your mistake */
               success: function(reponse){
                   alert(response);
                   window.location.href = 'index.html'; /* wherever you need */
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

EDIT: as I think (from your other post) you want user to be redirected, don't try doing this with `form-to-email.php` but according to response.

EDIT II: remove action from form just to make sure

Comment: On window.location.href - can I put 'index.html' or does it need to be linked to 'joshkelley.video' thanks!

Comment: hmm, I did window.location.href = 'joshkelley.video';

Comment: No errors, I get "Submit Successful!" but it doesn't take me back to joshkelley.video. You can go to the site if you want and test it. I also don't get an email. Thanks for your help in the matter. Feel like i'm back to square one.

Comment: Well I added e on the submitbutton function. Still not working for me. any ideas? also on the success: function() I changed to function(response). Still not doing what I need to do. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: @btetrick : I can't see jQuery function in your page when checking your website, and action path is still there. I would suggest a/ include jQuery in `head` section and call only `once` (there, you do it twice, locally) b/ run js for the form on its own and see what happens -> I feel like there can be conflict between your function used to `Scroll to the selected menu item on the page` as you target links